# JQuery TableSorter reload and sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

I think this question has been posted several times, but I cannot put the answers together. My script produces an HTML/JS site containing a `div` which contains only a `table`. When the function `refreshTbl` is called, it should reload the content of the `div` (this works) and sort the table within the way it was before (does not work). The table should again be sortable (does not work either).

```
var currentSort;

$(document).ready(
function() 
{ 
    $("#tbl1").tablesorter().bind("sortEnd", function(sorter) {
        currentSort = sorter.target.config.sortList; } );
}

);

function refreshTbl()
{
    $("#divtbl1").load(window.location.pathname + "?tableonly");
    $("#tbl1").tablesorter().bind("sortEnd", function(sorter) {
        currentSort = sorter.target.config.sortList; } );
    $("#tbl1").trigger("sorton", [currentSort]);
}
```

I also tried

```
    $("tbl1 tbody").load(window.location.pathname + "?tableonly");
```

and let the script only send the table body (without the preamble and the `tbody` tags). Did not work either.

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the [`.load()` function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is asynchronous. When javascript executes that code, the `.load()` function is called, then immediately the next statement is executed; but the table doesn't exist yet.

To solve this use the [`complete` callback](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) built into the jQuery `.load()` function.

Try this code:

```
var currentSort = [];

function init() {
  $("#tbl1")
    .tablesorter({ sortList: currentSort })
    .bind("sortEnd", function(sorter) {
      currentSort = sorter.target.config.sortList;
    });
}

$(function() 
{ 
  init(); 
});

function refreshTbl()
{
  $("#divtbl1").load(window.location.pathname + "?tableonly", function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status === "error") {
      console.error("ERROR!", xhr.status, xhr.statusText);
    } else {
      init();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: `$("#tbl1").trigger("sorton", [currentSort]);` after `init()` in the `else`-branch, and then it is perfect - thanks for the great answer.

Comment: It would be better to include the sort in the `init()` function: `$("#tbl1").tablesorter({ sortList: currentSort })`. And have the `currentSort` initially defined as an empty array.